# Admob Location using GPS

Tags: android, gps, admob

I've starting integrating Admob into my application tonight and on running it, now throughout my application, admob has enabled gps, in an attempt to find my position. My application occasionally requires GPS location features, but most of the time its safely disabled.

I am currently calling this, but it doesn't seem to have any allowance for which device to use for location.

```
AdManager.setAllowUseOfLocation(boolean)
```

How can I restrict AdMob to NOT use the GPS chip for its location sensing? Is this possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Location provider can be set using:

```
LocationProvider locationProvider =  LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
```

or

```
LocationProvider locationProvider =  LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
```

then

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(locationProvider, 0, 0, locationListener);
```

hope that helps